# Laravel multiple task sheduler is not working

Tags: laravel, task, scheduled-tasks

I was trying to execute two cron jobs by using Laravel task sheduler. I have written two separate classes for both of my tasks. First task is a method to send daily birthday wishes, an the other task is to check fee. These are my programs. Methods are written in controller files.This is how I called those classes in `Kernel`:

```
  protected $commands = [
     \App\Console\Commands\MonthlyFeeCheck::class, \App\Console\Commands\DailyBirthdayCheck::class,

  ];

   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
      // $schedule->command('inspire')
      //          ->hourly();
      $schedule->command('Fee:repeatCheck')
                    ->everyMinute();
      $schedule->command('Birthday:birthdayCheck')->daily();
    }
```

I have written two other command classes for both tasks. `DailyBirthdayCheck.php` and `MonthlyFeeCheck.php`, but this sheduler is not working. Can you please help me to resolve this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\StudentDetails;
use App\Models\StudentNotes;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use App\Http\Controllers\Student\StudentCommonController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

class DailyBirthdayCheck extends Command {

    protected $signature = 'Birthday:birthdayCheck';
    protected $description = 'check students birthday wishes';
    protected $process;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->student = new StudentCommonController();
        $this->dash = new DashboardController();
    }

    public function handle() {

        $this->dash->sendBirthDayWish();
    }

}
```

This is the code birthday check. I wrote the functions to send birthday wish on dashboard controller. Similarly, I have written another class for monthly feecheck

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\StudentDetails;
use App\Models\StudentNotes;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use App\Http\Controllers\Student\StudentCommonController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CommonController;

class MonthlyFeeCheck extends Command {

    protected $signature = 'Fee:repeatCheck';

    protected $description = 'check students fee mode and insert new entry in fee repeat table if the current period expires';
    protected $process;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->student = new StudentCommonController();
        $this->common = new CommonController();
        $this->dash = new DashboardController();
    }

    public function handle() {
        $this->student->checkStudentMonthlyFeeCrone();
        $this->common->getDocumentExpiringWeek();
    }

}
```

Comment: what "isn't working"? what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? and why would you be calling a controller at all, they have to do with requests and responses

Comment: Why didn't define this variable `$this->student,$this->common, $this->dash` in class `DailyBirthdayCheck, MonthlyFeeCheck` like `public $student` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your scheduler on the server?

E.g. by adding the following to cron:
`* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

This is explained in the section "Starting the Scheduler" on https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling

If you already have that covered, try changing from calling the commands using their command signature to using their classes instead, i.e.:

```php
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\MonthlyFeeCheck::class, 
    \App\Console\Commands\DailyBirthdayCheck::class,
  ];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->command(MonthlyFeeCheck::class)->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command(DailyBirthdayCheck::class)->daily();
}
```

Comment: Actually that feecheck was working early..now i have added that birthday option.. I will try ur suggestion.